# Pushing data from vue.js to flask rendered variable

Tags: javascript, vue.js, flask

I have a flask variable in which I am trying to use it as a ID inside the vu.js delimiters: ['[[', ']]']. So for example my flask id defined in `<p>` tag contains "emirates" word so from vue js I want to push string "hi" to that emirates id which is rendered by flask. I hope I am not sounding too confusing.

```
<i class="ui orange tiny label">
<p id="[[{{ i.App }}]]"></p> # This is flask rendered variable inside vue.js tag
</i>
```

Basically I want to push the data from vue.js to that ID. I am new to vue.js and not sure how to do it.

```
<script>
    var app = new Vue({
      el: "#app",
      delimiters: ['[[', ']]'],
      data: {
        "emirates": "Hi"
      }
    });
  </script>
```

In a nutshell, I want to push data from vue.js to the flask rendered variable

Comment: remember that python framework are server sided platforms  and vue is rendered on the client-side, so you'll not have access to this updated variable in flask. 

Anyway, you've set your delimiters to `[[]]` so you shouldn't use curly brackets.
Try using `<p id="[[ i.App ]]"></p> ` and see what happens?

Comment: @gugateider I have to use curly brackets because it contains flask variable.

Comment: Oh I understand now. You should be using the ref attribute. I will try to write an answer now for you

Answer (score 0):

The way I'd do is that I'd reference your element using the `ref` attribute. 
By doing that you'll be able to access the element inside your Vue component.

Once you have access to your element, you can get the `ID` attribute and assign that to a `Vue` variable. Then modify this variable according to your needs.

```js
window.onload = () => {
  new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data() {
      return {
        variable_test: '',
        variable_name: null
      }
    },
    mounted() {
      
         this.variable_name = this.$refs.my_element.getAttribute('id');
         this[this.variable_name] = 'hi';
           
    }
  })
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app"> 
   <!-- In your case here, id="variable_test"  should be your flask variable. -->
   <p id="variable_test" ref="my_element">
     {{variable_test}}
    </p>
</div>
```

Now `variable_test` ( which would be the variable name sent from 'flask' ) is changeable inside Vue.